# How to direct all files from a nested directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have trying to redirect many indexed PDFs such as

```
http://www.example.com/userfiles/file/my-pdf-name.pdf
```

to `http://www.example.com/`

with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/?userfiles/file/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Am I close, why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of the $1 and the '?'- like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/userfiles/file/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

EDIT: depending on your base address etc. you might instead want:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^userfiles/file/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```